# Parent POM version possibly not being honored by mvn 3.3.3 for properties resolution

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

This looks like a regression bug in mvn but I just wanted to confirm if I am not making an obvious mistake.

Assume I have a project structure like:

```
foo-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   -> foo-common 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (parent is foo-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
   -> foo-business 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (parent is foo-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

Say I have a property defined in `foo-parent` (`0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) as

```
<foo.bar.version>abc</foo.bar.version>
```

On checking the effective pom (using `mvn-3.2.1`) for `foo-business`, it correctly shows the `foo.bar.version`:

```
>mvn help:effective-pom -f foo-business/pom.xml | grep "foo.bar.version"
<foo.bar.version>abc</foo.bar.version>
```

I then installed these artifacts to my local repo (for the next steps of the bug reproduction).

Now if I make a change to `foo-parent`'s property and its version to `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`

```
foo-parent 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
   -> foo-common 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (parent is foo-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -- picked from local repo)
   -> foo-business 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (parent is foo-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -- picked from local repo)
```

property defined in `foo-parent` (`0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`) as

```
<foo.bar.version>xyz</foo.bar.version>
```

Again checking the effective pom (using `mvn-3.2.1`) for `foo-business`, it correctly shows the `foo.bar.version`:

```
>mvn help:effective-pom -f foo-business/pom.xml | grep "foo.bar.version"
<foo.bar.version>abc</foo.bar.version>
```

However, checking the same thing using `mvn-3.3.3`, it doesn't seem to use the property from the parent pom (`0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) but rather from the relative path (`../foo-parent`).

```
>mvn333 help:effective-pom -f foo-business/pom.xml | grep "foo.bar.version"
<foo.bar.version>xyz</foo.bar.version>
```

I think this to be a regression bug. Do you guys agree? I didn't see anything in the release notes that indicates this as a desired change in behavior.

Sample project setup for this @ https://github.com/kilokahn/maven-testers/tree/master/foo-parent

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a regression bug indeed; relative path shouldn't get priority if the versions are different. Best to [report the bug here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG/).

Comment: It looks like you are describing this: [MNG-5840](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5840)...I'm not 100% sure...But the problem i see here that you are referencing a parent with a different version than you have in your reactor which results in solving it via local repository...So i'm not sure if this is really a regression or bug...Your `foo-business` references a parent with `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT` ....

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks - I think the bug seems related and it looks like they fixed it in 3.3.8 (unreleased). Do you know if there is a way that one can download 3.3.8 to try it out? In general, from where do we download unreleased artifacts of maven? Do we need to checkout from github and build it out ourselves?( and it uses ant to build - ugh!)

Comment: You can if you like make a clone of the [Maven repository mirror](https://github.com/apache/maven) or you can clone from the [original git repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/maven.git) and you can use Maven 3.X what ever you like to build maven..you don't need Ant...you can use it but it is not neccessary..

Comment: thanks @khmarbaise. I used 3.3.9-SNAPSHOT (latest one in repo) and it is not showing the errant behavior. However, I do see that it is a problem with 3.3.8 also. I have noted it on [MNG-5840](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5840)

Comment: So 3.3.9 will be released (if we do not find any other blocker)...3.3.8 will never be released...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a problem in [MNG-5840](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5840) as noted by @khmarbaise. I was able to confirm that I don't see the errant behavior in apache-maven-3.3.9. Thanks to @khmarbaise